# Poster asked question, then deleted it once it was answered

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42882890) was asked. About 10 minutes later I answered it. About 1 minute later the OP deleted the question.

I'm annoyed that I wasted my time making the answer, and I want to punish [the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7676027/pythonguy) for doing this. My theory is that the OP deleted the question to hide that fact that s/he didn't understand what some code did. My theory is that s/he probably has done this before.

1. Is there any way for me (non-mod) to find out if this user engages in this behavior? (Can I search for deleted questions by this user?)
2. Is this a known issue in general (if not widespread), where people ask a question, get an answer, and then delete the question to hide the evidence? Anything to be done about it, other than removing the account?

**Edit**: Just [happened again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483839).

Comment: OP is likely going to be punished by the algorithm; deleting a question with an answer is seen as a terrible thing to do and will factor heavily into a question ban.  However, I don't see a reason for the question to *remain* deleted, so I've cast an undelete vote.

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [People deleting their own questions once they have an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108683/347499)

Comment: Do NOT punish people for wrong behavior. If you think something is the matter, flag the post for moderator attention.

Comment: "other than removing the account?" ... we usually don't delete accounts just because they have "REMUVED" the question for privacy. We do send them a message, if there's a repeated occurrence. If they ignore us, they'll be suspended. (1-3-7-30-365 days)

Comment: @BhargavRao To be clear, I was intending to suggest that *if* an account showed a pattern of bad behavior that it might be removed. Not that a single instance of this bad behavior warranted BALETION.

Comment: Gotcha, @Phrogz... If there's a pattern, then yep, we first warn and then  suspend them. Deletion is the last resort.